# How to hide the title of blog post and only show the H1 title?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, page-title

I want to show the title of my blog post to only search engines and want to show h1 title to my readers inside my blog post.

But whenever I write the title on WordPress and hit update. It shows me both title as well as the h1 tag.

So it is quite annoying to me as well as for readers.

I have installed "title remover" plugin and I can't see the title now in the blog post. So the problem is solved.

But I want to know is there any other way to hide title but only show in search results?

I have attached screenshots to understand better. Basically, I see on many Blogs that they only show title on the search result pages but when we click we get to see h1 tag inside the posts.

I want to show only title for search pages and not in blog posts inside.
Here is the screenshots
[Wordpress interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKp40.png)

[Blog Page where I want only H1 to show and not title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJQ7o.png)

[Title Remover Plugin Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpg4p.png)

I want to know is there any other way to remove title from blog post?

Comment: Post some code that you've tried and maybe we can help you.

Comment: hard to understand what is your issue Show us at least some screenshots of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have edited it see now

Comment: You  will probably have to edit the template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely there is an easy fix to this, you need to browse your theme and find your post template - wp-content->themes->my_theme_name. Now different themes may have a different file/folder structure but usually in the root theme folder the file that displays your posts is called single.php Open up this file and you'll see the WP loop calling for the template that will output your post content - something like this - http://joxi.ru/YmE6BlxC0W5jR2 When you locate your template which outpust your posts content you will see the the_title() - the function that 'prints' your posts title - http://joxi.ru/4AkknX4IyGZR8A

Answer (score 0):

Edit css of your blog title and add this css code

```css
.post-title {
    display: none;
}
```